# Spring MVC Handle Unique Constraint Violation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring MVC application that uses Spring Data JPA for persistence with Hibernate as my JPA provider. I have a database table with a unique constraint on a column, hence why saving the corresponding entity may result in a unique constraint violation. I would like to detect if this happens within my service layer so that I can present a meaningful error message to the user. Below is my service method.

```
@Service
public class IndustryServiceImpl implements IndustryService {
    @Autowired
    private IndustryRepository industryRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(Collection<Industry> industries) {
        this.industryRepository.save(industries);
        this.industryRepository.flush();
    }
}
```

And my Spring Data JPA repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface IndustryRepository extends JpaRepository<Industry, Integer> { }
```

Now when a unique constraint violation happens, I get the following exception (shortened for brevity):

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    ...

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    ...

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "industry_name_unique_index"
  Detail: Key (name)=(SomeValue) already exists.
  ...
```

As you can see, the "main" exception is of type `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`, which is a quite general exception. Ideally I would like to catch an exception that tells me that the error was due to a unique constraint violation. Therefore I have a few  questions:

1. Is it correct that the exception should be of type `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`, or is that because the Spring exception translation is not kicking in? And can I configure Spring to give me less general exceptions, for example [DuplicateKeyException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException.html)?
2. If this behavior is not related to missing exception translation, then do you know of a better way of detecting the more specific error than calling `e.getCause()`? I could easily do this, but this does not seem right to me for two reasons; first of all, the code would seem more "fragile" to me, and secondly, I would also have to check for a JPA provider specific exception, as the nested exception is of type `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`. If possible, I would like my service to not be aware of which JPA provider I am using.

Below is my persistence configuration in case it is relevant.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.company.repository", "com.example.account.repository" })
public class PersistenceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @Value("${jndi.data.source}")
    private String dataSourceName;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);

        return dsLookup.getDataSource(this.dataSourceName);
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        String[] packagesToScan = new String[] { "com.example.company.entity", "com.example.account.entity" };
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        factory.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        factory.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE); // Prevents errors when using custom validators when persisting
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(this.entityManagerFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would say you should be explicitly validating the data rather than relying on exceptions.

Comment: @AlanHay Yes, I am in fact doing that, but if a phantom read occurs, then this scenario might still happen (although the chances are slim) - and I don't want to lock the table. I might also need an answer to this question in other contexts. :-)

Comment: @AlanHay you can't validate against unique db constraints in a busy server

Comment: Fair enough. Anyway, I have tested this locally and regardless of whether or not I actually register a PetPostProcessor in app config I get back the following so translation does happen: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException > javax.persistence.PersistenceException > org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Comment: @AlanHay Hmm, it is strange that this is not the behavior I get. If you have any ideas for what could be wrong or if you want me to post some more code, then please let me know. I really appreciate you taking the time to test this - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring enables exception translation to be applied transparently through the `@Repository` annotation. The postprocessor automatically looks for all exception translators (implementations of the PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface) and advises all beans marked with the @Repository annotation so that the discovered translators can intercept and apply the appropriate translation on the thrown exceptions.

In summary: you can implement DAOs based on the plain persistence technology’s API and annotations, while still benefiting from Spring-managed transactions, dependency injection, and transparent exception conversion (if desired) to Spring’s custom exception hierarchies.

`

```
<!-- Exception translation bean post processor -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="myProductDao" class="product.ProductDaoImpl"/>
```

`

Taken directly from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html).

Also, you can take a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-dialect).

HTH.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I already use the `@Repository` annotation, and I have also configured exception translation as in the above code example. So it should be working, right?

Comment: Yeah, I guess the pure JPADialect fits your needs. But then again, we thought the normal stuff did too. Will need to implement and see. Will try to do this and get back to you if possible.